# Need a query that will satisfy two conditions from two tables

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

table a and table b, table a has two field, field 1 and 2, and table b has two fields, field 3 and 4.

```
where
     tablea.field1 >= 4 and tableb.field3 = 'male'
```

is something like the above query possible, Ive tried something like this in my database although there are not errors and i get results, it checks whether both are true separately.

im going to try to be abit clear, and cant give out the query outright as much as i would like to (University reasons). so ill explain, table 1 has several columns of information one of which is number of kids, table two has more information on said kids, like gender.

so im having trouble creating a query where first it checks that a parent has 2 kids but two male kids, thus creating a relationship between parent table and kids table.

```
CREATE TABLE parent
(pID NUMBER,
numberkids INTEGER)

CREATE TABLE kids
(kID NUMBER,
father NUMBER,
mother NUMBER,
gender VARCHAR(7))

select
    p.pid
from
    kids k
    inner join parent pm on pm.pid = k.mother
    inner join parent pf on pf.pid = k.father,
    parent p
where
    p.numberkids >= 2 and k.gender = 'male'
/
```

this query checks that the parent has 2 kids or more and the kids gender is male, but i need it to check whether the parent has 2 kids and OF those kids is there 2 or more male kids (or in short to check whether the parent has 2 or more male kids).

sorry for the long winded explanation i modified the tables and the query from the one im actually going to use (so some mistakes might be there, but the original query work, just not how i want explained above). any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't you have an Equals Sign "=" at the end? `k.gender = 'male'`? Also, `INNER JOIN` is the same as `JOIN`.

Comment: yes mistake in my writing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best thing to do would be to take the `numberKids` column out of the `parent` table ... you'll find it very difficult to maintain.

Anyway, something like this might do the trick:

```
SELECT p.pID
  FROM parent p INNER JOIN kids k
    ON p.pID IN (k.father, k.mother)
 WHERE k.gender = 'male'
 GROUP BY p.pID
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2;
```

Comment: Sorry about that ... must have been too quick on the trigger.